# Color of first and last point in a graphic

Tags: graphics, random

I'm trying to make a graphic of a random walk in 1D, but i want that the first and the last point have a color (in this case the first one red and the last blue), but i dont know what i'm doing wrong..

This is my code:

```
RandomWalk[n_, d_] := 
NestList[(# + Table[Random[Real, {-1, 1}], {d}]) &, Table[0, {d}], 
n];

OneDim = RandomWalk[5000, 1];

firstpoint = OneDim[[1]]

lastpoint = OneDim[[5001]]

ListPlot[{{Hue[0], PointSize[.02], 
Point[firstpoint]}, {Hue[.7], PointSize[.02], Point[lastpoint]}, 
Line[OneDim]}]
```

Comment: my mistake, i want in 1D not in 2D, sorry

Comment: random walk in 1D? will be hard to see the path?

Comment: my teacher ask that, i know that i can have the graphic with:

   ListPlot[OneDim]

but i would like to have the first and last point with a different color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. The structure of your 1d output is not optimal, because you get something like `{{x1},{x2},...}` which means a nested list. To make it short, if you want to use `ListLinePlot`, you can do it with the help of `Epilog`, which draws your first and last points on the final graphics:

```
oneDim = RandomWalk[500, 1];
ListLinePlot[Flatten[oneDim], 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[.04], Red, Point[{1, oneDim[[1, 1]]}], Blue, 
   Point[{Length[oneDim], oneDim[[-1, 1]]}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another way is to use `Graphics` directly and just draw a line through all your points and mark the start and end points:

```
With[{data = MapIndexed[Join[#2/10, #1] &, oneDim]},
 Graphics[{Gray, PointSize[.02], Line[data], Red, Point[data[[1]]], 
   Blue, Point[Last[data]]}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Please note that I used `MapIndexed` to transform your 1d list into a list `{{t1,x1},{t2,x2},...}` where the `t`'s are the increasing time.

Comment: thanks for help, but i just want with one coordinates because is 1D. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @MarianadaCosta This is the way 1D random walks are visualized! Please read here: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk)

Comment: @halirutan That's why labeling axes is important :)

Answer (score 4):

Ok, here it is 1D, not sure if I understood the question right, but see if this what you want

```
randomWalk[n_, d_] := Table[{RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 0}, {n}];
data = randomWalk[50, 1];

ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> PointSize[.01], PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-.1, .1}}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[.02], Red, Point[data[[1]]], Blue, Point[data[[-1]]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: exactly what i wanted, thanks :D